# Angular2 styleUrls not loading external styles

Tags: angular

Working on an angular2 application and had hoped to be able to load different styles for public content and admin content. However it seems Angular ignores styles loaded from an external source

```
@Component({styleUrls:["http://url_to_external_styles"]})
```

Above code doesn't work as expected, is there any other configuration required for loading styles from external source using full URL? Loading the styles relative to component works 100%, am however more interested in loading from content server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable the view encapsulation of the component:

```
@Component({
    styleUrls:["http://url_to_external_styles"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation

Comment: I understood view encapsulation as a means of controlling usage of shadow DOM, along with enabling styles to spill from parent to child component. Nevertheless I loaded styles using relative path assets/path_to_css. They load as expected, with the exception of font awesome which is loaded from node_modules/..., the font awesome CSS loads, but icons are not rendered. GOAL: Am trying to use one index.html for both public module and admin module with different styles without resulting to JavaScript hacks to write directly to the head.

Comment: @iswak is this still part of the above problem? Can you post an example?

Comment: I have asked question in separate thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126234/angular2-best-way-to-handle-public-and-admin-application-one-app-or-multiple-ap regarding having one app which performs multiple functions. An app which is both a CMS and and Admin system. Am beginning to think it is best to have as two separate angular applications. Will reduce maintenance and remove complexity in managing styles and and and... Thanks for your help, hope you can share some of your thoughts in new question.

Comment: Tried this suggestion but still getting compile errors:Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './https://my.external.css." I've imported ViewEncapsulation from angular/core and added encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to the @Component directive. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

For those getting errors of the form "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './the-url-of-an-external-style-sheet' ", here's what worked for me:

Here's what the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) has to say about urls in the styleUrls array:

> The URL is relative to the application root, which is usually the location of the index.html web page that hosts the application.

In order to get the style sheets to load, make a local css style sheet and add @import statements to the top of it. For instance, if you want to add the style sheet at "http://url_to_external_styles", you could make a src/app/my-component.component.css file. Then you could add the following as the first line of src/app/my-component.component.css:

```
@import "http://url_to_external_styles";
```

You can find out more about @import by following the link in the Angular documentation quoted above.

Comment: Thank you! For the compiler to work, I had to use this syntax.
@import url("http://url_to_external_styles");